# How to count consecutive times a character appears in a String

Tags: java

I have the code

```
public static int count(String text, char letter)
{
    int amount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(text.charAt(i) == letter)
            amount++;
    }
    return amount;
}
```

to count how many times a certain letter appears in a String (ex: `eeeeee` has 6 `e`'s).

But how would I go about returning the number of times a character appears consecutively with only one String parameter?

For example:

- `AAbcde` would return `1` (one `a` after the first `a`)
- `abcde` would return `0` (no consecutive count)
- `abccd` would return `1` (one `c` after the first `c`)
- `aabccc` would return `3` (one `a` after the first `a` + two `c`'s after the
  first `c`)

Is there any simple way to achieve this similar to the code I already have?

Comment: One question I would have is comparison of uppercase vs lowercase. For example, should ```Aa``` return ```1``` or ```0```?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try next code

```
  public static int count(String text)
{
    int amount = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(i-1))
            amount++;
    }
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: `charAt` fails with most characters.